# Which IP class do ISPs use?

Tags: ipv4

I have been learning about address classes, public and private ips, etc and was wondering which class A, B, or C ISPs typically use to distribute public ips? I was guessing it would be class A, allowing for the maximum amount of networks but I am not sure if I am grasping the concepts properly.

Comment: Keep reading. You're still decades away from modern networking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Network classes were deprecated in 1995 (20 years ago), so any mention of IPv4 classes is basically historical. Today, we use Classless Interdomain Routing (CIDR) and Variable Length Subnet Masks (VLSM) which make classes moot.

Which classes an ISP may use depends on what address space is allocated to the ISP. The large ISPs most likely have addresses in multiple classes, but some of the smaller ISPs will only have blocks from one class. You can't generalize, and you would need to check with a specific ISP.

Answer (score 6):

Address classes have been deprecated more than 20 years ago. The internet uses Classless Inter Domain Routing (CIDR) now and the old classful system is only relevant for some ancient routing protocols that you shouldn't be using anyway.

I am sorry, but you just learned about some obsolete technology... Unless you're interested in history you should forget all that classful stuff as soon as possible.